# Is there a way to remove gaps in my CSS3 Grid, and center the grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I created a parent Div with 3 children Div's within it. I want each of the 3 Divs to be on the same column, but on the centre of the screen with 10px separating the border from each other, while still maintaining the 3 boxes centred on the screen together.

I have a very basic grasp on CSS3

```css
#prices {

        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: 1fr;
        margin: auto;
    }



    #tenor,
    #bass,
    #valvet {
        border: 1px solid;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 360px;
        height: 330px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 10px;

    }

    #tenor {
        justify-self: end;

    }

    #bass {
        justify-self: center;
```

```html
<!-- Beginning of HTML5 Code -->


    <div id="prices">
        <div id="tenor">
            <h3>TENOR TROMBONE</h3>
            <h4>$600</h4>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum.<br>
                Lorem ipsum.<br>
                Lorem ipsum dolor.<br>
                Lorem ipsum.
            </p>
            <button class="btn">Select</button>

        </div>

        <div id="bass">
            <h3>BASS TROMBONE</h3>
            <h4>$900</h4>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum.<br>
                Lorem ipsum.com<br>
                Lorem ipsum dolor.<br>
                Lorem ipsum.
            </p>
            <button class="btn">Select</button>

        </div>

        <div id="valvet">
            <h3>VALVET TROMBONE</h3>
            <h4>$1200</h4>
            <p>
                Plays similar to a Trumpet.<br>
                Great for Jazz Bands.<br>
                Lorem ipsum.
                <p><button class="btn">Select</button>
                </p>
        </div>


    </div>
```

With the code above, everything is centered perfectly, but there are huge gaps between each of the 3 boxes. How do I remove the gaps, but make sure its still centered relative to the screen?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you used grid-gap? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap

Comment: @vitrualman89, You mean to say you don't want the gap between the grid boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS flex property to achieve this

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nyu6f82a/1/)

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
 #prices {
display: flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
margin: auto;
}
#tenor,
#bass,
#valvet {
border: 1px solid;
width: 100%;
max-width: 360px;
height: 330px;
text-align: center;
margin: 10px;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="prices">
<div id="tenor">
    <h3>TENOR TROMBONE</h3>
    <h4>$600</h4>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum.<br>
        Lorem ipsum.<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor.<br>
        Lorem ipsum.
    </p>
    <button class="btn">Select</button>

</div>

<div id="bass">
    <h3>BASS TROMBONE</h3>
    <h4>$900</h4>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum.<br>
        Lorem ipsum.com<br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor.<br>
        Lorem ipsum.
    </p>
    <button class="btn">Select</button>

</div>

<div id="valvet">
    <h3>VALVET TROMBONE</h3>
    <h4>$1200</h4>
    <p>
        Plays similar to a Trumpet.<br>
        Great for Jazz Bands.<br>
        Lorem ipsum.
        <p><button class="btn">Select</button>
        </p>
</div>


</div>

</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one your using **margin: 10px;** these three #tenor, #bass, #valvet ids. If you don't want the gap between the grid columns you have to use **margin: 10px 0;** in these three #tenor, #bass, #valvet ids.

```css
#prices {
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    margin: auto;
}
#tenor,
#bass,
#valvet {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 360px;
    height: 330px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<body>

<div id="prices">
    <div id="tenor">
        <h3>TENOR TROMBONE</h3>
        <h4>$600</h4>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum.<br>
            Lorem ipsum.<br>
            Lorem ipsum dolor.<br>
            Lorem ipsum.
        </p>
        <button class="btn">Select</button>

    </div>

    <div id="bass">
        <h3>BASS TROMBONE</h3>
        <h4>$900</h4>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum.<br>
            Lorem ipsum.com<br>
            Lorem ipsum dolor.<br>
            Lorem ipsum.
        </p>
        <button class="btn">Select</button>

    </div>

    <div id="valvet">
        <h3>VALVET TROMBONE</h3>
        <h4>$1200</h4>
        <p>
            Plays similar to a Trumpet.<br>
            Great for Jazz Bands.<br>
            Lorem ipsum.
            <p><button class="btn">Select</button>
            </p>
    </div>


</div>

</body>
</head>
</html>
```